# how to convert timestamp format to date-format in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, type-conversion, unix-timestamp

How to convert timestamp 1470989229.000014 to date format `mm-dd-yyyy` in java?
I could do it for different timestamp formats but I could not parse this one.

The database used is MySQL so the timestamp probably would be in that format.

Comment: Please add the code showing what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

first question, what programming language did you used?

in case you're using PHP, you can try `date("mm-dd-yyyy", (1470989229.000014))` but if you want the result like `08-12-2016` , you can use `date("m-d-Y", (1470989229.000014))`

Answer (score 0):

In `MySQL` you can do this using `FROM_UNIXTIME` followed by `DATE_FORMAT` function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1470989229.000014),'%m-%d-%Y')
```

And the output(`mm-dd-yyyy`) would look like below:

`08-12-2016`

<kbd>[**Demonstrated Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/74358/0)</kbd>